# Javascript function repeat old call, when call it the second times

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

I want to pass value to a js function many times, but at the after call, js function will execute with old parameter, then execute again with new value
I have the html:

```
<a onclick="deleteConfirm(1,'abc')" href="#" class="badge badge-danger">Delete</a>
<a onclick="deleteConfirm(2,'def')" href="#" class="badge badge-danger">Delete</a>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
function deleteConfirm(id, title) {
        var delmodal = $('#deleteModal');
        delmodal.find('.modal-body').text(title);
        delmodal.modal('show');
        $('#deleteBtn').click(function () {
            delmodal.modal('hide');
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("DeleteConfirmed", "Admin")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
            dataType: "json",
                success: function (recData) {
                    var notify = $.notify('<strong>Thành công</strong><br/>' + recData.Message + '<br />', {
                        type: 'pastel-info',
                        allow_dismiss: false,
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    var notify = $.notify('<strong>Lỗi</strong><br/>Không xóa được<br />', {
                        type: 'pastel-warning',
                        allow_dismiss: false,
                    });
                }
        });
        });
    }
</script>
```

The first click on the badge, value is 1,'abc', but the second click on the second link,the values still be 1,'abc',after that, it will call again with new value 2, 'def'.

Comment: Working fine for me

Comment: After success call ajax, i receive error message because the post of the first id was deleted, but after that i see both post was deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i realized that $('#deleteBtn').onclick add a EventListener to the element.

It is called every time when #deleteBtn is clicked, so multiple event listeners are attached to deleteBtn. That's why my ajax was called multiple times.

Solution (just move event out of the function):

```
<script>
function deleteConfirm(id, title) {
        var delmodal = $('#deleteModal');
        delmodal.find('.modal-body').text(title);
        delmodal.modal('show');
    }
$('#deleteBtn').click(function () {
        delmodal.modal('hide');
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("DeleteConfirmed", "Admin")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ id: id }),
        dataType: "json",
            success: function (recData) {
                var notify = $.notify('<strong>Thành công</strong><br/>' + recData.Message + '<br />', {
                    type: 'pastel-info',
                    allow_dismiss: false,
                });
            },
            error: function () {
                var notify = $.notify('<strong>Lỗi</strong><br/>Không xóa được<br />', {
                    type: 'pastel-warning',
                    allow_dismiss: false,
                });
            }
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have cached JS file on your browser with the same file name. You can try `ctrl + f5` to reload ignoring cached content.

Comment: Thankyou, but there are another ways to do that without refreshing my page ?

Comment: You can stop caching from your browser settings. you might find this helpful - http://devtoolsecrets.com/secret/performance-disable-the-browser-cache.html

Comment: Another approach can be adding a version number to file, which might be helpful in production.

Comment: after debugging, i saw that the js function was repeated with old value, and new value ever since

Comment: can you be more descriptive about your #deleteModal contents? Share the snippet maybe?

Comment: It is just a bootstrap 4 modal with id deleteModal

Answer (score 0):

You can add a version to script source link like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?1500"></script>
```

change 1500 to version number you like

Comment: after debugging, i saw that the js function was repeated with old value, and new value ever since